# Duplicate elements in java.util.Set

Tags: java, set

`java.util.Set` implementations removes the duplicate elements.

How are duplicates elements deleted internally in a `java.util.Set`?

Answer (score 19):

Actually AFAIK from the sources most `Set` implementations in java don't even check if the element is already contained.

They just always execute the `add()` on their internal structure which holds the set elements and let that object handle the duplication case.

e.g. `HashSet` calls `put(K,V)` on the internal `HashMap` which just inserts the new object overwriting the old entry if duplicate.

Comment: `<E> java.util.Set.of(E... elements)` throws `IllegalArgumentException` if any duplicate is found.

Answer (score 12):

Reading a little into your question I'm guessing that you're seeing strange behaviour with a `java.util.HashSet` (typically what everyone uses by default).

Contary to the contract of `java.util.Set` it is possible to get the same object in a `java.util.HashSet` twice like this:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class SetTest 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    MyClass myObject = new MyClass(1, "testing 1 2 3");

    Set<MyClass> set = new HashSet<MyClass>();
    set.add(myObject);

    myObject.setHashCode(2);
    set.add(myObject);

    System.out.println(set.size());  // this will print 2.
  }

  private static class MyClass 
  {
    private int hashCode;
    private String otherField;

    public MyClass(int hashCode, String otherField) 
    {    
      this.hashCode = hashCode;
      this.otherField = otherField;
    }

    public void setHashCode(int hashCode) 
    {
      this.hashCode = hashCode;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) 
    {    
      return obj != null && obj.getClass().equals(getClass()) && ((MyClass)obj).otherField.equals(otherField);
    }

    public int hashCode() 
    {
      return hashCode;
    }
  }
}
```

After the pointer from @jitter and a look at the source you can see why this would happen.

Like @jitter says, the `java.util.HashSet` uses a `java.util.HashMap` internally.  When the hash changes between the first and second *add* a different bucket is used in the `java.util.HashMap` and the object is in the set twice.

The code sample may look a little contrieved but I've seen this happen in the wild with domain classes where the hash is created from mutable fields and the equals method hasn't been kept in sync with those fields.

Comment: Modifying objects in a HashSet in a way that modifies their hashCode()/equals() results produces undefined behavior.

Comment: @Joachim - exactly, but it doesn't mean it doesn't happen.  Infact, the equals/hashCode methods generated by the popular IDEs often cause the hashCode to change as an object is mutated.

Comment: Arguably the hashcode *should* change if the object is mutated - after all, it needs to be consistent to `equals()`, so it needs to change if an object would no longer be considered equal to its pre-mutation state.  The real problem here is using mutable objects as HashMap keys; it's *highly* recommended to only use immutable objects, otherwise you open yourself up to this kind of randomness, as generally speaking `hashCode()` *must* change as a mutable object is mutated.

Comment: @dtsazza - the hashcode doesn't necessarily need to change when an object is mutated as equal hashcodes don't imply equality (and as the example above shows, changing the hash after instantiation can be dangerous).

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to find this out is to look in the source for the code you are interested in.

Each JDK has a src.zip included which contains the source code for the public classes so you can just locate the source for HashSet and have a look :)  I often use Eclipse for this.  Start it, create a new Java project, set the JVM to be an installed JDK (if not you are using the system default JRE which doesn't have src.zip), and Ctrl-Shift-T to go to HashSet.

Answer (score 0):

Read your question more detailed:

You can't add duplicates, from java doc for Set.add() or do you mean addAll?:

Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present (optional operation). More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if the set contains no element e2  such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)). If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false. In combination with the restriction on constructors, this ensures that sets never contain duplicate elements.

Answer (score 0):

Adds the specified element to the set if it is not already present.
If the set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false.In combination with the restriction on constructors, this ensures that sets never contain duplicate elements.

Answer (score 0):

First off, set doesn't "Delete" duplicates, it doesn't allow entering duplicates in the first place.

Let me walk you through the implementation of set.add(e) method.

set.add(e) returns boolean stating whether e has been added in the set or not.

Let's take this simple code for example:
[image]

We will get x as `true` and y as `false`.

Let us see what add() actually does:
[image]

So, HashSet basically uses HashMap internally, and sends the element as key (and an empty initialized object called PRESENT as the value.).
This `map.put(k,v)` either returns a null, if the key never existed, or it would return the old value which the key had.

Therefore while doing `set.add(1)` for the first time, we get null in response of `map.put(1,PRESENT)`, and that's why we get `true`.

And when we call it the second time we don't get null in response to `map.put(1,PRESENT)` and hence the `set.add(1)` returns `false`.

(You can dig deeper into the put method, which internally calls putVal and uses hash to identify if a key is already existing, depending on which it returns a null or old Value.)

**And since we are using HashMap internally, which uses hash to find uniqueness of a key, we would never end up having same element twice in a HashSet.**