# Hashset allows duplicates?

Tags: java, duplicates, hashset

This question surely isn't a new one, but I didn't find any helpful answer anywhere.

As you can see in the code below, the equals and hashcode methods are overriden, but it still allows duplicates. The Hashcode has been generated automatically by Netbeans.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    TaskDetails other = (TaskDetails) o;
    if ( (id_subtask == other.id_subtask)
            && ((date.compareTo(other.date)) == 0) )
    {
        System.err.println("Duplicate Entry"+id_subtask+" + "+other.id_subtask);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Good!" +id_subtask+" + "+other.id_subtask);
        return false;
    }

} 

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 71 * hash + this.id_subtask;
    hash = 71 * hash + this.id_team_member;
    hash = 71 * hash + Float.floatToIntBits(this.nb_hours);
    hash = 71 * hash + (this.date != null ? this.date.hashCode() : 0);
    hash = 71 * hash + (this.comment != null ? this.comment.hashCode() : 0);
    hash = 71 * hash + (this.subtask_name != null ? this.subtask_name.hashCode() : 0);
    System.out.println("Hash : "+hash + "Subtask : " + id_subtask);
    return hash;       
}
```

This the code used to add an entry into the hashset :

```
TaskDetails newTaskDetails = new TaskDetails
                                (
                                    s.getId_subtask(),
                                    mus.teamMember.getId_team_member(),
                                    f,
                                    mysqlFormat.format(caldate),
                                    c.substring(0, Math.min(c.length(), 100)),
                                    s.getName_subtask()
                                );

                            allTasks.add(newTaskDetails);
```

(allTasks being the Hashset)

This code is used in function A and B.

If only function A is executed, it works fine. If function B is executed after function A (so the code above is executed twice), then the hashset suddenly accepts duplicates, even though system.err is triggered saying there is a duplicate entry?

Is there a flaw in the code, or am I just missing something?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I suspect something manipulating newTaskDetails due to which hashvalue is being changed.

Comment: for what class are you overriding those methods?

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "accepts duplicates"? Is the entire object the same, or do you just mean dupicate ids?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java HashSet is allowing dupes; problem with comparable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961350/java-hashset-is-allowing-dupes-problem-with-comparable)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you are using 2 fields to consider 2 objects to be "equal", but you are using more than 2 fields to construct the hashcode.  your `hashCode()` method *cannot* be more specific than your `equals()` method.  as a good rule of thumb, your `hashCode()` method should not use any fields that your `equals()` method does not use (it can use fewer however).  to put it more technically, if 2 objects are "equal" they *must* have the same hashcode (the reverse is not required).

Comment: Thanks jtahlborn and Jochen! It seems to work for now! This is probably why the hashcode for some objects were the same.

Answer (score 3):

You are violating the consistency requirement between hashCode() and equals(). If two objects are equal according to equals(), they must also have the same hash. Because your equals only considers two fields, and hashCode considers more, this requirement is not met.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question, see my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642210/duplicate-elements-in-java-util-set/1642520#1642520).

The behaviour where a `java.util.HashSet` allows duplicates is caused when the hash code of the objects in the `java.util.HashSet` can change.

This typically happens when an object's hash code is constructed from mutable fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the implementation of `hashCode()` does not match `equals()`. Both methods **must** use the same attributes of your object.

It's likely in your implementation that the `hashCode()` is different even if `equals()` evaluates to `true`. In this case (different `hashCode`s) the objects are different for the `HashMap`.

Please correct your implementations to use the same attributes. Then the error should vanish.

Answer (score 0):

From the [javadoc of `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

```
If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then
calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the
same integer result.
```

Your hashcodes are different for two objects that are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, so the other code `HashSet` is going to make the wrong assumptions, and return the wrong results.

Some code is written in a manner that they depend on other objects honoring "contracts".  Your class doesn't honor the `Object` contract, so nothing in collections can be assumed to work, as collections requires that the `Object` contracts not be broken.