# Removing duplicates from the list of objects based on more than one property in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to remove duplicates from the list of objects based on two properties, this question would be similar to below link but I am trying to find uniqueness based on two properties using java 8 features.

example: I have custom object where two property together makes unique entry

say List customers

customerName and DOB together makes unique entry.

Any solution to identify distinction using predicate for two properties.
like below link they have solution on one property.
[Java 8 Distinct by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property)

Similar question:

[Remove duplicates from a list of objects based on property in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670116/remove-duplicates-from-a-list-of-objects-based-on-property-in-java-8/29671170)

Comment: You need a getter-function `get2Id()` which return the unique ID and use this function in the example you found.

Answer (score 13):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29672489/2711488) of the linked question already points to a working solution, as you can easily use `List` containing all property values as keys, e.g.

```
HashSet<Object> seen=new HashSet<>();
customers.removeIf(c -> !seen.add(Arrays.asList(c.getName(), c.getDayOfBirth())));
```

If these properties are never `null`, you could use Java 9’s `List.of` instead of `Arrays.asList` which is potentially more efficient.

---

If you want a Stream solution creating a new `List`, you could use

```
List<Customer> distinctCustomers = customers.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toMap(c -> Arrays.asList(c.getName(), c.getDayOfBirth()),
                         Function.identity(), (a,b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new),
        m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values())));
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution,indeed it worked and sorry for late reply.

Comment: @Pavanks no problem. But keep in mind that you can [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to mark the problem as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution would be is to implement a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface for your Class that would compare your class based on the properties of your interest. Then compare the instances for equality using your Comparator.

Answer (score 0):

1. Override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in `Customer` object and include the relevant fields.
2. Use `java.util.Set` instead of `java.util.List` and just add the objects to the Set.

This will assure you don't have any duplicate objects in the Set.
See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642210/duplicate-elements-in-java-util-set) for more info.

**Update:**

After overriding `equals()` you can do the following:

```
List<Customer> distinctCustomers = customersList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

*distinct() documentation:*

> java.util.stream.Stream
>   public abstract Stream **distinct()**
>   Returns a stream consisting of the **distinct** elements (**according to Object.equals(Object)**) of this stream.

Comment: Thanks,  actually i am looking for some solution using java 8 features rather than Override equals and hashcode. something like below link.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670116/remove-duplicates-from-a-list-of-objects-based-on-property-in-java-8

Comment: nvm, I was wrong (at least for HashSet) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204082/

Answer (score 0):

For distinct() on a stream to work, we need to override both equals and hashCode method of an object.

```
<list or set>.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```