# Remove duplicates from a list of custom objects based on two fields

Tags: java, stack-trace, logfile

I have two lists of custom objects both are `List<LogEntry>`. The properties inside one are `typeOfException`, `date` and `stackTrace` and the other just contains `typeOfException` and `stackTrace`. What I would like to do is to remove duplicate Log entries based on their `typeOfException` and the `stackTrace`. The way I've defined a unique stack trace is to be if the first 'at line' is the same i.e

```
[25/05/21 10:28:41:481 BST] - IllegalStateException some text here
at com.google MyClass(Line 50)
[28/05/21 10:28:41:481 BST] - IllegalStateException some more text here
at com.google MyClass(Line 50)
```

are seen as duplicates but

```
[25/05/21 10:28:41:481 BST] - IllegalStateException some text here
at com.google MyClass(Line 50)
[28/05/21 10:28:41:481 BST] - IllegalStateException some more text here
at com.google MyClass(Line 50000)
```

would be seen as unique.

I have a `List<LogEntry>` called `logEntries` which contains the `date, typeOfException` and `stackTrace`. I have another `List<LogEntry>` called `logEntriesToCheckForDupes` which is a `LogEntry` object but this time just containing `typeOfException` and the top at line of the `stackTrace` (Note all the properties are Strings).

The code I have so far is

```
HashSet<Object> uniqueStackTraces =new HashSet<>();
    logEntryObjectsToCheckForDupes.removeIf(c -> !uniqueStackTraces.add(Arrays.asList(c.getTypeOfexception(), c.getStackTrace())));
```

which I think works (not entirely convinced as I go from 887 exceptions to only 14). Is there some method/logic to find the index of each unique entry. That way rather than creating a new HashSet I could just store a list of unique indexes and create a `List<LogEntry>` from `logEntries` of every object with a unique index?

I'm quite perplexed and not sure my code is actually working as intended so any suggestions/input is much appreciated. The question is similar to  ([Removing duplicates from the list of objects based on more than one property in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563377/removing-duplicates-from-the-list-of-objects-based-on-more-than-one-property-in))and I used some logic from here.

Comment: Have you written any test cases, it could be your code is right.  Perhaps loop though the list print out the object and using a text edit manually delete the duplicates and see what your answer is.  Having taken a quick look the answers in the link question seem good to me.

Comment: I haven't written any test cases yet, I spent a while looking through the actual Log File in notepad and it doesn't seem too unrealistic. I think seeing the initial list Size go to 14 from almost 900 was just a shock! I think mainly now I just need some way to find the index of these unique log entries so I can have my full log entry object with date/exception and stack trace. Or some other path to get these.

Answer (score 0):

Group and aggregate:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<LogEntry> list1 = IntStream.range(0, 100).mapToObj(i -> random(true)).collect(toList());
    List<LogEntry> list2 = IntStream.range(0, 100).mapToObj(i -> random(false)).collect(toList());

    // join removing dups, get the last date
    Collection<LogEntry> result = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
            .collect(toMap(
                    // the key (better use a Tuple<> type instead concatenate strings)
                    x -> x.typeOfException + ":" + x.stackTrace,
                    x -> x,
                    // the max non null date
                    (a, b) -> a.date == null ? b : b.date == null ? a : a.date < b.date ? b : a))
            .values();

    result.forEach(e -> System.out.printf("%s, %s, %d%n", e.typeOfException, e.stackTrace, e.date));
}

@AllArgsConstructor
static class LogEntry {
    public String typeOfException;
    public String stackTrace;
    public Integer date;

    public static LogEntry random(boolean withDates) {
        ThreadLocalRandom rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
        return new LogEntry("E" + rnd.nextInt(3), "S" + rnd.nextInt(3), withDates ? rnd.nextInt() : null);
    }
}
```

with output

```
E2, S1, 1974693605
E1, S0, 2085047733
E2, S0, 1766963016
E0, S2, 2106321704
E0, S1, 1752799219
E1, S2, 2123681998
E1, S1, 1522756354
E0, S0, 1578552430
E2, S2, 1969494110
```

if we have few with date null appear

```
List<LogEntry> list1 = IntStream.range(0, 4).mapToObj(i -> random(true)).collect(toList());
List<LogEntry> list2 = IntStream.range(0, 100).mapToObj(i -> random(false)).collect(toList());
```

with output

```
E2, S1, null
E1, S0, null
E2, S0, null
E0, S2, 2123867824
E1, S2, null
E0, S1, 13858484
E2, S2, null
E1, S1, 1347419477
E0, S0, -135848900
```

Comment: This might be a silly question so apologies, list 1 and list 2 are going to be my two lists in this case aren't they? You've just used them as an example to show an output?

Comment: Yes @ConnorGill , given your two lists the result you expect is on `result = ...`.